# Local Hamiltonian and combinatorial search problems

Tags: co.combinatorics, quantum-computing, quantum-information, physics

I was going through the [PhD thesis of Daniel Nagaj](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2117). At the beginning of chapter two he indicated a relation between the local Hamiltonian perspective of adiabatic quantum computation and combination search problem. I am not getting the intuition behind this. Let me quote from the second paragraph of the chapter.

> There is hope that there may be combinatorial search problems, defined
>   on $n$ bits so that $N = 2^n$ , where for certain “interesting” subsets of
>   the instances the run time of the Quantum Adiabatic Algorithm grows
>   sub-exponentially in $n$. A positive result of this kind would greatly
>   expand the known power of quantum computers.

I understand that it is possible to implement the Grover's algorithm as an adiabatic quantum algorithm. What I don't understand is the special relation between local Hamiltonian and combinatorial search problems. Any clue?

Comment: Just to clarify, I would like to know an example of local structure in a combinatorial search problem.